Expected stopping time for biased random walk with increasing stepsize
Let $S_n$ be a stochastic process, with
$$
S_{n+1} = S_n - 1 + \begin{cases}
n^2 & \mathrm{with\;probability\;}\frac{1}{2}\\
-n^2 &\mathrm{else}
\end{cases}.
$$
Let now $T:=\inf\{n\geq0:S_n\leq0 \}$ be a stopping time of the process, when it first becomes negative.
Is $\mathbb{E}(T)$ finite?
I know, that for the, somewhat related, stochastic process $S'_n$ (starting from $n\geq1$) with
$$S'_{n+1} = S'_n-\frac{1}{n^2}+\begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{with\;probability\;}\frac{1}{2}\\
-1 &\mathrm{else}
\end{cases},
$$
and the analogous stopping time $T'$, it holds that $\mathbb{E}(T')=\infty$ (since $\sum^\infty_n \frac{1}{n^2} = 2$).
While the ratio between the "constant part" and the "quadratic part" is the same for both processes, intuitively the required number of steps in the negative direction decreses for the process $S_n$, while it stays the same for $S'_{n+1}$.
Furthermore, a proof by contradiction, like in this question does not work.
How could I show, whether $\mathbb{E}(T)<\infty$?
